# combining two different sets of queries

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table and the population is with respect to each city.

```
City state country population
c1   s1   co1   100000
c2   s1   co1   100000
c3   s1   co1   100000
c11  s2   co1   100000
c12  s2   co1   100000
```

And I need the output as follows

```
s1 300000
s2 200000
co1 500000
```

Can anyone help in doing this using sql server or Teradata would be appreciated

Comment: Try with `SUM`, `GROUP BY` and `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Try to teach yourself language called SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` :

```
select col, sum(population)
from table t cross apply
     ( values (state, population), (country, population) 
     ) tt(col, population)
group by col;
```

You can also use `union all` for other DBMS :

```
select t.state, sum(t.population)
from table
group by t.state
union all
select t.country, sum(t.population)
from table
group by t.country;
```

Answer (score 1):

apply works as yogesh says but this might be easier to understand

```
 select 'state' as t, state as s, sum(population) as total
 from table_you_did_not_name
 group by state

 union all

 select 'country' as t, country as s, sum(population) as total
 from table_you_did_not_name
 group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 different groupings and then combine them with UNION:

```
select state column1, sum(population) column2
from tablename
group by state
union all
select country, sum(population)
from tablename
group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is calculate them saparately and union together

```
select  state, sum(population)
from table 
group by  state
union all 
select country,  sum(population)
from table 
group by  country
```